# After modifying the PayPal IPN URL, still using old IPN listener URL for some notifications

Tags: paypal, payment-gateway, paypal-ipn, paypal-subscriptions

I'm working on a project which has PayPal integration. We have two PayPal accounts for payment and choose the PayPal account based on the type of users. We previously had two IPN listeners for the two different PayPal accounts. Previously our IPN was pointed to "https://www.old-domain1.com/paypal/ipnhandler" and "https://www.old-domain2.com/paypal/ipnhandler". Yesterday we have updated two websites into one and we started to use a common IPN to this address "https://www.new-domain.com/paypalipn/paypal/IpnHandler" to the new project.

We have added the common IPN URL on both PayPal accounts. But we could see PayPal is still sending the IPN to the old IPN handler for the old recurring payment. Our old IPN handler URLs are not currently working and we don't have the option to update the payment if PayPal is still sending the notification to the old URL. For some users, it worked correctly. For some users PayPal still using the old IPN URL. Why does this happen?

Now we have one IPN listener for two different PayPal accounts. Is this related to the problem?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If a URL was specified as part of setting up the transaction (i.e. by the software/site when the user was redirected to PayPal), that transaction-level specification supersedes any setting in the PayPal account. It is now set in stone for anything related to that transaction/recurring profile, and cannot be changed.

Comment: Thank you @Preston PHX, You are correct. PayPal support replied to me about the issue as "Specifically for recurring payments, there is not a method to update the IPN URL after the recurring payment profile is created. Unfortunately, this would require that the subscription be canceled and that the buyer resubscribe. "